# Can we send java objects as part of message in GraphX pregel API?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-graphx, spark-bagel

​I am sending an java complex java object as message in pregel API in graphX and I am getting following error at runtime

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source) at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source) at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.graphx.util.BytecodeUtils$.getClassReader(BytecodeUtils.scala:91) at org.apache.spark.graphx.util.BytecodeUtils$._invokedMethod(BytecodeUtils.scala:67) at org.apache.spark.graphx.util.BytecodeUtils$.invokedMethod(BytecodeUtils.scala:41) at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl.accessesVertexAttr(GraphImpl.scala:298) at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl.mapReduceTriplets(GraphImpl.scala:210) at org.apache.spark.graphx.Pregel$.apply(Pregel.scala:124) at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphOps.pregel(GraphOps.scala:362) at com.ulb.code.wit.main.TestGraph$.main(TestGraph.scala:32) at com.ulb.code.wit.main.TestGraph.main(TestGraph.scala)

can anyone give any idea why this is happening.

Comment: As far as I know, GraphX only works with Scala...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also don't use tag [tag:apache] for Apache Spark questions.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Why would it? Lack Java API doesn't mean you cannot use it.